# In AWS Amplify, how can I recover records that failed to sync?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

After I added S3 storage:

```
amplify add storage
```

and performed an

```
amplify push
```

I then received this message:

[image]

(posts is just the name of the table).

As you can see, I've added two new records with the app, but all prior records were lost.

How can I prevent this happening in the future, and can I recover the unsynced records?